# Unable to copy files based on Name property

Tags: file, powershell

I wrote a Powershell script to get the content of a folder and also to check if the items meet a particular criteria. If they do, they should be moved to a particular directory.

The challenge I'm having is that the script moves all the content of the folder either they fulfill the criteria or not.

```
$source = "E:\GatewaysRenditionArea\pdf"
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $source
ForEach ($file in $fileList) 
{
    if ($file.FullName-like "*PID*.pdf")
    {
        copy-Item -Path $source -Destination "E:\Gateway\GatewaysStagingArea\PID - Piping and Instrumentation Diagram"
    }
    Else
    {
        if ($file.FullName -like "*BOM*.pdf")
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination "E:\Gateway\GatewaysStagingArea\BOM - Bill of Materials"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing the `FullName` property. Is that on purpose?

Comment: I had compared the Name property before, but since i didn't get the desired result i changed it to the Nmae property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify this:

```
$Path = 'E:\GatewaysRenditionArea\pdf'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*bom*.pdf' |
    Copy-Item -Destination 'E:\Gateway\GatewaysStagingArea\BOM - Bill of Materials'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*pid*.pdf' |
    Copy-Item -Destination 'E:\Gateway\GatewaysStagingArea\PID - Piping and Instrumentation Diagram'
```

Remember: Filter left, format right.

Comment: With this approach, it means an if/Else statement is not needed right?